# How to authenticate users?

Tags: authentication

I have the following scenario.

At my company we use Oracle 11g. The authentication on the frontend is using database users. So, every user of the frontend has a his own user account in the database system.

This implies that they have the ability to connect directly to the database, if they know the IP address, port, etc,. Of course, this is not considered a security concern because our strict managment of roles and privileges. This also implies that when a new user is added our DBA have to create the user and assing the proper roles and privileges.

Until now, our frontend is accesed only by our internal users. However, We are planning to add the capability for our external users can login in our frontend.

Our estimation is about 750,000 external users with annual increments of 50,000. This users are supposed to access our system three or four times per year.

The question we have is how to grant access to this users.

- By using our already implemented authentication system. Every user has his own database user account.
- Generating an authentication system for external users only. Like most of the CMS's in the market, with tables as an ACL (Access Control List) for users, passwords and roles for our 750,000 external users.

My main concern is to have +750,000 database user accounts that will be unused most of the time and eventually could make a mess with our internal users.

Someone have a similiar experience with this amount of users and how did you deal with it?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head..

- Make sure that whatever outward facing boxes are few in number.
- For the boxes that can connect to the database - make them purely 
  authentication or get/put for the data. don't run the web server on the databases or on the same LAN segment.
- If possible encrypt communications from the client to the database so that if any of your intermediate hops get rooted they'll only see junk.
- Use a firewall to ensure that only the bare minimum can get through.
- For validating authentication, don't let their 'real' password get off the web server. Keep it hashed, San Diego!